# Fast Search Crawl. Failed to Authenticate

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

We have a brand new SharePoint 2010 SP2 Enterprise farm with a standalone Fast Search Server. I've done the configuration according to the article here http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/deploying-fast-search-server-2010-sharepoint

Everything looks good apart from the fact that fast search cannot crawl items.

Here are the symptoms:

- The crawler goes over a lot of documents but ultimately fails with an error (see below)
- I receive an error in the Windows Event logs on the SP server (not sure if it's related):

[image]

- I cannot access http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc because of on error:
  [image]
- When I'm trying to use the command docpush -U -c sp http://site/Pages/Home.aspx it gives me an error:
  [image]
- Claims To Windows Token Service is running on all servers (if it matters)
- The same problem is present when I'm crawling applications with both Claims-based authentication and Windows Authentication

[image]

[image]

[image]

The search account has Full control to the web application

**Additional Info**

- Fast Search 2010 SP1
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with .net 3.5.1 (SP1)
- Anonymous access is enabled
- I can access the crawled content with the account that is used for crawling

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

I've removed all bindings from both WFEs:
[image]

Here is the standard IIS bindings for SharePoint Web Services. Looks like all the rest of the services work with no errors
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error with STS services is telling me that you may have multiple host header bindings on the same IIS web site. As WCF only supports one binding per IIS Web Site.

Could you please check your web application in IIS and check the bindings. please read this blog, almost on end the same error discussed. http://mrhodes.net/tag/maintenance/

Comment: yes, I saw it. I deleted all bindings except of one. The error is still the same

Comment: Try to recycle sts app pool n then browse it....how many wfe you have?

Comment: I will try to recycle everything in 15 mins. I have 2 WFEs and 1 App server. Frankly, I've removed bindings only on one of the WFEs. The one I'm trying to access. I'll remove bindings from boths servers

Comment: you should remove it from both server and are you using load balancer? and FQDN as DNS for web site url?

Comment: I'm not using DNS yet, but I've got host entries in all servers. they resolve either to themselves or to the first WFE. I guess, I can setup NLB and DNS to point to the WFEs soon

Comment: I've created a standard (not FAST) SharePoint Search application. Crawling the content now. Let's see if the problem is the same

Comment: Update: Standard SharePoint Search is able to crawl the same content with no problems